# Nodejs Async get request

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

I made a small application that makes async calls to an api (local in this case). The target application will make a million of calls per day.

With maxSockets set to 1 I had a time of 45 seconds. With maxSockets = 10, the execution time has dropped to 40 seconds.

How can I make this code go faster please?

```
var request = require('request');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'testAPI'
});
var inputData = [];
for(i=1; i<=9999;i++){
    inputData.push('number' + i);
}
var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost/test.txt',
    maxSockets: 10
};
var limit = inputData.length;
var counter = 0;

var fetch = function(file,cb){
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var time = (new Date().getTime()/1000)
            connection.query("insert into testAPI (name) values ('" + time + body +"')", function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //console.log('Inserted: ' + time + body)
                counter++;
            });
        }
    })
}

async.map(inputData,fetch,function(err, results){
    if ( err){
        // either file1, file2 or file3 has raised an error, so you should not use results and handle the error
    } else {
        options.count = i;
//        request(options, fetch)
        // results[0] -> "file1" body
        // results[1] -> "file2" body
        // results[2] -> "file3" body
    }

})
var checkIfFinished = setInterval(function(){
    if(counter === limit){
        console.log('finished')
        connection.end();
        clearInterval(checkIfFinished);
    }
},1000)
```

Comment: why are you polling whether or not something is finished using `setInterval` when you're using a control flow library like `async`? BTW your bottleneck in this code is likely to be the async resource rather than anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a control-flow library, you don't poll. That's what the callbacks are for. They get called when operations complete. That's how you know you're done.

Let's start by eliminating dependencies as they are black boxes, and we don't really know how they are built. If you use newer versions of Node.js, you can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which should pretty much replace `async`. As for `request`, you can simply use Node's [`http.get`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) to read the remote file.

All your API calls can also be transformed into promise-returning functions. If you can't find an existing module that already does it for you, you can simply wrap the call in a Promise and call `resolve` or `reject` accordingly. What I normally suggest is to split operations into a promise-returning function, and leave it to the caller to chain them up. In this case, `log` manages the sequence of `readFile` and `insertToDb`.

```
function insertToDb(body){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var time = Date.now();
    var query = `insert into testAPI (name) values ('${time}${body}')`;
    connection.query(query, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

function readFile(file){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(url, body => {
      if(error) reject(error);
      else resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

function log(file){
  return readFile(file)
    .then(fileData => {
      // Now we have read the file, time to insert to db
      return insertToDb(fileData);
    }, error => {
      // Failed to read file
    })
    .then(fileData => {
      // Insert succeeded, we conclude by resolving with the file contents
      return fileData;
    }, error => {
      // DB operation failed
    });
}
```

`async.map` simply just calls each value against an iterator then calls the callback when everything's done. This is something easily done with `array.map` and `Promise.all`. We can use `array.map` to call `log` and collect the returned promises to an array, then we use `Promise.all` to wait for all promises to resolve.

```
Promise.all(inputData.map(file => log(file))).then(results => {
  // results[0] -> "file1" body
  // results[1] -> "file2" body
  // results[2] -> "file3" body

  console.log('finished');
}, () => {
  // Something failed
});
```

Now reading a remote file 9999 times (and over HTTP) and writing to the db 9999 times in rapid succession is the real bottleneck here. You're essentially flooding both servers. Even on `localhost`, servers still have CPU and memory constraints. No matter how you make this script run faster, the script will run no faster than the slowest of the two.

I believe what you're simply doing is trying to log changes of the file into the DB. I suggest you read and insert at a slower interval, like say every 5 seconds. That should give the servers enough time to breathe. Besides, do you really need to read the file in a way that reads are milliseconds apart. That's some file you got there.

Other alternatives would be to stream the data instead of reading the file at an interval. For the DB, try looking into solutions like Redis.

A few other things:

- You can use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) instead of string concatenation to build strings.
- Instead of `new Date().getTime()`, use `Date.now()`. Does the same thing without creating a new `Date` object.
- `fetch` isn't really "fetching", it appears to read a file and store it to the DB. It's technically "logging". Name your variables and functions properly.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

What I am really trying to do is to open 1,000,000 records from a local database and for each of these records make an API call to a server over VPN.

That is why I have decided to use request library -  It allows to limit amount of sockets used by  the application. I don't want to DDOS the server on the other side of the VPN.